# Dom4j: error "incompatible types" on compilation

Tags: java, dom4j

I am developing a small desktop application in Java. I came across a point where i need to read data from XML file, for this i am using Dom4j library. While coding i am facing the following error could anyone guide me in resolving this error:

```
public void FromXML(String sXMLFileURI)
    {//Reads the XML File and Stroe Data in Calling Object
      Document document = getDocument( sXMLFileURI );
      String xPath = "myXpath";
      List<Node> nodes = document.selectNodes( xPath );//This line gives the followiing error:

//error "incompatible types
//required: java.util.List<org.dom4j.Node>
//found:    java.util.List<capture#1 of ? extends org.dom4j.Node>"
          for (Node node : nodes)
          {   
             //some processing here
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the method signature is

```
List<? extends Node> selectNodes(String)
```

your variable `nodes` should be of type `List<? extends Node>`, and not of type `List<Node>`.

A `List<Node>` accepts any `Node` instance as element. Whereas a `List<? extends Node>` is a `List<Node>`, or a `List<Element>`, or a `List<Attribute>`, or a list of some other subclass of `Node`. You just don't know which one.

Answer (score 5):

It's a consequence of the fact that java generic collections are not "covariant". Method selectNodes() returns a list of Objects all of which implement Node. But this is not a `List<Node>`. You have to change the declaration to

```
List<? extends Node> nodes=...
```